# Writing netty performance tests

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, netty

So I have a netty-based websockets client that I am using for performance tests.  My idea is that I can use it to simulate 100, 1000, etc simultaneous connections.

I've determined that my current approach to this is not working--the test harness is simply not creating enough websocket connections, althogh it bumps along happily, thinks it's still connected, etc.  But my server simply does not show the correct number of connections when I use this test harness.   I think most likely this is occurring because I am using various objects in the netty library across multiple threads at once and they don't handle that very well. ClientBootstrap, for example.

This is what I am doing per-thread.  Can you tell me where I am going wrong, so that I can fix my test harness?

```
public void run(){
    try{

       // client bootstrap.  There is one of these per thread.  is that part of the problem?
       ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(new NIOClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool())));

       Channel ch = null;

       try{
           // set up ssl engine
           final SSLEngine engine = createServerContext().createSSLEngine();
           engine.setUseClientMode(true);

           // there is a new handhsaker per thread, too.  They all go to the same uri 
           final WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = new WebSocketClientHandhsakerFactory().newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V08, null, false, null);   

           // set up the pipeline factory and pipeline
           bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelieFactory(){

               @Override
               public Channelpipeline getPipeline() throws Exception(){
                   ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
                   pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
                   pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder();
                   pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder();
                   // WebSocketClientHandler code not included, it's just a custom handler that sends requests via websockets 
                   pipeline.addLast("ws-handler", new WebSocketClientHandler(handshaker);
                   return pipleline;
               }
            });

           // connect websockets preflight over http
           ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
           future.sync();

           // do websockets handshake
           ch = future.getChannel();
           ChannelFuture handshakeFuture = handshaker.handshake(ch);
           handshakeFuture.syncUninterruptably();
           Thread.sleep(1000);  // i had to add this.  Sync should have meant that the above method didn't return until it was complete... but that was a lie.  So I sleep for 1 second to solve that problem.  

           if(!handshakeDuture.isSuccess())
               System.out.println("WHOAH errror");

           // send message to server
           ch.write(new TextWebSocketFrame("Foo"));

           // wait for notifications to close
           while(!getShutdownNow().get())  // shutdownNow is an atomicBoolean which is set to true when all my threads have been started up and a certain amount of time has passed
              Thread.sleep(2000);


           // send close; wait for response
           ch.write(new CloseWebSocketFrame());
           ch.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();



           }

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a [benchmark test from azinman](https://gist.github.com/azinman/779303) in github, it is in scala but not hard to understand and use same principles in java. Maybe it can be helpful to achieve your goal.

Comment: I created a load generator client in .NET to develop my own websocket component, it may be useful: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketEchoLoadGenerator